# Android capturing video error

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to capture video from camera and save it to memory card, I'm using [google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video) and I still gets an error when calling

```
mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera); // 4.b.1 step from tutorial
```

I have try to put it in `try` and see the exception

```
try {
    mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.d("MyVideoRecord", "Error setting the camera: " + e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("CameraPreview::record() - setCamera() thrown an exception");
    System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    System.out.println("Exception: "+e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();

    return false;
}
```

LogCat output

```
D/MyVideoRecord(2681): Error setting the camera: null
I/System.out(2681): CameraPreview::record() - setCamera() thrown an exception
I/System.out(2681): Exception: null
I/System.out(2681): Exception: null
I/System.out(2681): Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(2681): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(2681):     at com.example.myvideorecord.CameraPreview.record(CameraPreview.java:101)
W/System.err(2681):     at com.example.myvideorecord.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:104)
W/System.err(2681):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
W/System.err(2681):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:969)
W/System.err(2681):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
W/System.err(2681):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
W/System.err(2681):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
W/System.err(2681):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:468)
W/System.err(2681):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:126)
W/System.err(2681):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
W/System.err(2681):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
W/System.err(2681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err(2681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err(2681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
W/System.err(2681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(2681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err(2681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
W/System.err(2681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
W/System.err(2681):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm(2681): Debugger has detached; object registry had 425 entries
```

It looks like **mCamera** pointer is null from the log, but I dont think thats the case as I have unlocked **mCamera** right before without error.
I have looked in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setCamera%28android.hardware.Camera%29) but there isn't any word about `setCamera()` returning an error or throwing an exception. I have set `CAMERA`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `RECORD_AUDIO` permissions in manifest. I don't know what may be causing the problem or how to trace it. Could anyone please help me?

Thank you very much ! :)

---

Here is all my code:

**CameraPreview.java**

I have implemented `record()` (that's wher error occurs) and `stopRecord()` methods. Rest of file is from google tutorial.

```
package com.example.myvideorecord;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

//http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private boolean recording;
        private MediaRecorder mRecorder;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            System.out.println("CameraPreview() - Started");
            mCamera = camera;
            recording = false;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

            System.out.println("CameraPreview() - Ended");
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            System.out.println("CameraPreview::surfaceCreated() - Started");
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("MyVideoRecord", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            System.out.println("CameraPreview::surfaceCreated() - Ended");
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            System.out.println("CameraPreview::surfaceDestroyed()");
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            System.out.println("CameraPreview::surfaceChanged() - Started");

            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
              // preview surface does not exist
              return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
              // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
            // reformatting changes here

            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("MyVideoRecord", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            System.out.println("CameraPreview::surfaceChanged() - Ended");
        }


        public boolean record()
        {
            // if already recording, return
            if( recording ) return false;

            // We are recording
            recording = true;
            // log start of the method
            System.out.println("CameraPreview::record() - Method start");

            //mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.unlock();


            // 
            // !!! THIS IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS !!!
            //
            //
            try {
                mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d("MyVideoRecord", "Error setting the camera: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("CameraPreview::record() - setCamera() thrown an exception");
                System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                System.out.println("Exception: "+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

                return false;
            }

            // Set media recorder properties            
            mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mRecorder.setProfile( CamcorderProfile.get( CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW ) );
            //mRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
            mRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/MVR_video");

            // probably not needed
            //mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay());

            // Prepare media recorder
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MyVideoRecord", "Error preparing media recorder: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("CameraPreview::record() - prepare() thrown an exception");

                return false;
            }

            mRecorder.start();

            System.out.println("CameraPreview::record() - Method returning TRUE");
            return true;
        }

        public void stopRecord() {
            System.out.println("CameraPreview::stopRecord() - Method start");

            if(recording)
            {
                mRecorder.stop();
                mRecorder.release();
                mCamera.lock();
            }
        }    
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myvideorecord;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

// http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private Camera.Parameters parameters;
    private FrameLayout preview;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_preview);               

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Get parameters of camera (not neccessary now)
        parameters = getCameraParameters(mCamera);
        parameters.getFocusMode();

        // get preview reference
        preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

        preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.        

        System.out.println("MainActivity::onCreate() - adding view to preview");
        preview.addView(mPreview);
        System.out.println("MainActivity::onCreate() - view added");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();     
        System.out.println("MainActivity::onStop() - Method start");

        // here shoud go something like
        // preview.stop
        preview.removeView(mPreview);
        mPreview.stopRecord();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Save all needed information
        //preferences.edit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("MainActivity::onDestroy() - Method start");

        mCamera.stopPreview();
        releaseCameraInstance(mCamera);
    } 



    /*
     * 
     *  MENU 
     * 
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        System.out.println("MainActivity::onCreateOptionsMenu() - Method start");

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        System.out.println("MainActivity::onOptionsItemSelected() - Method start");

        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_quit:
                this.finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_record:
                mPreview.record();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }



    /*
     * 
     *  Camera handling
     * 
     * */
    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            System.out.println("getCameraInstance() - excepction");
        }

        System.out.println("getCameraInstance() - returning camera");
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    public static Camera.Parameters getCameraParameters(Camera c)
    {
        System.out.println("getCameraParameters() - getting parameters of camera");
        Camera.Parameters par;
        par = c.getParameters();

        System.out.println("getCameraParameters() - returning parameters of camera");
        return par;
    }

    /* release camera object and log it */
    public static void releaseCameraInstance(Camera c){
        System.out.println("releaseCameraInstance() - camera released");
        c.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: here the link for camera video capture example code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633758/android-recording-a-video-initializing-the-camera/13634040#13634040

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mRecorder` is null as you never initialize it. Initialize this in the constructor along with the camera and other things ;)

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
```

Comment: Thank you very much...
I feel embarrassed to forget on such an elementary thing :)

Comment: all goods, these things are usually hard to spot in your own code. but quite obvious for someone when they see it for the first time. i've done it heaps of times myself hahaha